# How to use radio button to not send data to the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able with the radio button and a little javascript to toggle between the two categories, but even if one category is hidden it's data still sends.

### challenge.rb

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :oneshot,  -> { where(categories: 'One-Shot') }
    scope :ongoing,  -> { where(categories: 'Ongoing') }
```

### _form

```
<%= form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :action %>
  <% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>
    <%= label(c, c) %>:
    <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher", checked: (c=='One-Shot')) %>
  <% end %>

  <div id='id_of_first_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :deadline %>
  </div>

  <div id='id_of_second_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :date_started %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<script>
  $(function(){
     $('#id_of_second_div').hide();
     $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ 
        $('#id_of_first_div').show().attr('disabled', false); 
        $('#id_of_second_div').hide().attr('disabled', true); 
     });
     $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){
       $('#id_of_first_div').hide().attr('disabled', true); 
       $('#id_of_second_div').show().attr('disabled', false);
     });
  });
</script>
```

### Radio Button HTML

```
<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="One-Shot" checked="checked" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_one-shot" />

<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="Ongoing" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_ongoing" />
```

### Adapting Fiddle

```
  <input id='a-selector' type='radio' name='selector' value='A' checked/> A
  <input id='b-selector' type='radio' name='selector' value='B'/> B
  <div id='details'>  
    <div id='for-a'>
      <%=  f.date_select :deadline, include_blank: true, selected: Date.current %>
    </div>
    <div id='for-b'>
      <%=  f.date_select :date_started, include_blank: true, selected: Date.current %>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
var removed = $('#for-b').detach();

$('#a-selector').click(function() {
  $('#details').append(removed);
  removed = $('#for-b').detach();
})

$('#b-selector').click(function() {
  $('#details').append(removed);
  removed = $('#for-a').detach();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a form element as `disabled` only disables user interaction with it; it doesn't remove it from the form's data (although your jQuery code is actually setting the div to disabled, which does nothing, but fixing that wouldn't help at all).  What you want to do instead is clear the value of the date elements, e.g.,

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     $('#id_of_second_div').hide();
     $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ 
        $('#id_of_first_div').show();
        $('#id_of_second_div').hide();
        $('#id_of_second_div select').value('')
     });
     $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){
       $('#id_of_second_div').show();
       $('#id_of_first_div').hide();
       $('#id_of_first_div select').value('')
     });
  });
</script>
```

Though for that to work, you will need to add `include_blank: true` as an option to your `date_select` tags:

```
<%= f.date_select :deadline, include_blank: true %>
```

This will add the empty value as an option to your date selects, so that the above code can reset them to that empty value.

I'd also like to note -- all of this is just front-end logic, which any malevolent (or curious) user can circumvent. Your backend code (i.e., your controller) should handle discarding the fields you don't need based on your business logic, too.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com: that's a bit tricky, because you want the current date to be the default except when the field is hidden. I think you might have more luck by, instead of just hiding the date selection fields, removing them from the DOM entirely and re-inserting them when needed. [This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzr6sdhk/) gives an example of that. Let me know if you need help with that approach.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com what part of it doesn't work? Are there any errors showing up in the Javascript console? Do both select fields show up, or just one?

Comment: Actually it did work made a slight mistake :] Thank you so much for your help!